# Using spanish language characters in csv file name

Tags: javascript

I have a csv filename as **Todos los artículos en la anulación de Informe_Sep 6, 2012 10.49.41.csv**.I'm unable to read this file which is located in a specific 'url'. This occurs only in IE8 and IE9. It works fine in other browsers and in English language.

The issue is because of using **í,ó** characters in the file name.

I'm using the below code to open the save as dialog box but it throws

**HTTP 404.The webpage cannot be found**

**Code :** 
window.open(url, '_blank');

Please help me with this issue.

Comment: Its been a while with no response how are you getting on ?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried the escaped version ?

> Todos%20los%20art%EDculos%20en%20la%20anulaci%F3n%20de%20Informe_Sep%206%2C%202012%2010.49.41.csv